# is it possible to use the same asio::io_context of an asio::serial_port for an asio::steady_timer?

Tags: c++, timer, serial-port, boost-asio

using asio library, I want to use timeouts for an `asio::serial_port` read/write calls.

Is it possible to use the same `asio::serial_port` `asio::io_context` and the same `read_handler` used for an `asio::async_read` call, so that in any case (read completion or timeout) event will triger the `read_handler` handler, (with different error codes of course).

Any possible suggestion will be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Many examples in the library and documentations will show you this, and it might be one of the most important design goals: integrating all kinds of different asynchronous APIs and devices in one interface.

Just look at the library examples https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html or alternatively the many examples on this site: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bboost-asio%5d%20deadline_timer%20timeout

Comment: The problem is that **ReadHandler** and **WaitHandler** have different signatures. And should I call `asio::io_context::run();`? because that context is already in use by the `asio::serial_port` `async_read`  function.

Comment: I'd say you just need to try it. You'll see how it works soon enough. Of course you need to run the service (or nothing would happen). But you typically need to call it once only. It's the service that schedules various async operations. Did you look at the examples? They would clarify it even quicker.